# Mysql select duplicate and tag as duplicate but exclude latest

Tags: mysql, duplicates, tagging

I want to tag a certain value as duplicate if it shows more than once in my table but it should exclude the latest value in my row if it is the latest.

Here my table.

```
ref_id | access
1234     2015-10-04 10:01:10
1234     2015-10-04 10:02:10
1234     2015-10-04 10:03:10
```

Here is what I want to happen

```
ref_id | access               | tag     
1234     2015-10-04 10:01:10    duplicate
1234     2015-10-04 10:02:10    duplicate
1234     2015-10-04 10:03:10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ref_id, access, 
       IF((SELECT 1 
           FROM mytable AS t2 
           WHERE t1.ref_id = t2.ref_id AND
                 t2.access > t1.access LIMIT 1) = 1, 'duplicate', '') AS tag
FROM mytable AS t1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39062/1)

Alternatively you can use a `JOIN` to the record having the maximum date value:

```
SELECT t1.ref_id, access, 
       IF(t1.access < t2.max_access, 'duplicate', '') AS tag
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ref_id, MAX(`access`) AS max_access 
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY ref_id
) AS t2 ON t1.ref_id = t2.ref_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39062/3)

To `UPDATE` you can use:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ref_id, MAX(`access`) AS max_access 
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY ref_id
) AS t2 ON t1.ref_id = t2.ref_id
SET tag = 'duplicate'
WHERE t1.access < t2.max_access;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/959b8/1)

Comment: What if I I already have an existing tag column and I just want to update it to value duplicate?

Comment: Thank you for the update query. Anyway,when I run this query the access seems to change to today's date. Any explanation why?

Comment: I am able to know why the date on access is auto updating to today's date. It's data type is timestamp the update current_timestamp is turned on. So turning it off did the trick. ;)